# Range of the constant of integration

Tags: calculus, integration

So I was asked this during an examination interview: "Does the constant of integration have a range?"

I am most certain that it doesn't. But the interviewer didn't seem pleased with the answer. So is there really a range of values for the constant of integration?

Comment: I wonder why those answers say "real number" and not "complex number"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be any real number (corresponding with your answer).

But this can also be rephrased as "its range is $\mathbb R$" (maybe corresponding with what the interviewer had in mind).

---

**edit**:

In my view your answer is correct: a **constant** is actually not "ranging" over some set. It is not a variable, and even if it was then "domain" would be better than "range".

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct: the constant of integration can be any number. Of course, in specific contexts it may be true that a certain constant is more appropiate than another one, but in the general case each constant is as good as any other.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the constant of integration refers to the $C$ in the following.

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= f(x)$$

$$y = \int f(x) \, dx + C$$

The constant $C$ can be any real number as it will vanish upon differentiation.